# Issue: Importing csv with phpMyAdmin Works, Php Script treats csv import differently

Tags: php, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I've been working with this script which I believe is a bit antiquated. The issue I'm having is when I import a csv file(6000+ records) using phpMyAdmin it work fine, however, when I import the same csv file with this php script it corrupts the field order.

Only the first two records are imported. The 2nd record imported does not import correctly as the first field of the second record, is included in the last field of the first record thus it seems the import process is not recognizing the line break for the next record. I tried saving the csv file as utf8, as well as, ascii. In either scenario it does not make a difference.

Any ideas to modifying the script to treat the csv file the same way phpMyAdmin does?

```
<?php

include "connect.php"; //Connect to Database

$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE plfwinvtable"; //empty the table of its current records

mysqli_query( $conn, $deleterecords );

//Upload File

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {

        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";

        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";

        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);

    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database

    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $import="INSERT into plfwinvtable(Barcode, Brand, Description, Category, Price, Size, Unit, ServeOz, NumDrinks, NameVar) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $import) or die(mysqli_error());

    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";

    //view upload form

}else {

    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";

    print "File name to import:<br />\n";

    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>
```

Comment: `Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.`

Comment: Mark I think you may be on to something as I am using an older mac and filemaker to create my csv file. My client has a shared hosting account w/cpanel. Hopefully I can change this setting on the server.

Comment: You should be able to change the `auto_detect_line_endings` setting dynamically from within your code using [ini_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: I'm looking for an example how to do this in a php script. How would you do this and where in the script would you add this.

Comment: `ini_set ('auto_detect_line_endings', true)`. The [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) actually use this as an example in the notes

Comment: Hey Mark, This seemed to partially fix the issue as now when I import I get 66 records. If I change the sort order in the csv file I get 125, thus there seems to be an issue with the data. The import feature in phpMyAdmin seems to be much more forgiving than php.

Comment: apostrophes in the fields caused the import issue

Answer (score 0):

Save file as **upload.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #E3F4FC;
    font: normal 14px/30px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #2b2b2b;
}
a {
    color:#898989;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    color:#CC0033;
}

h1 {
    font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #CC0033;
}
h2 {
    font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #898989;
}
#container {
    background: #CCC;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 945px;
}
#form           {padding: 20px 150px;}
#form input     {margin-bottom: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="form">

<?php

include "inc/database.php"; //Connect to Database

//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into awards (field1, field2, field3, field4) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";

    //view upload form
}else {

    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";

    print "File name to import:<br />\n";

    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

will work 100%... :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what issues you are facing now? working fine at my end.

Comment: Im connecting using mysqli connection.

Comment: As I stated above the script does not treat my csv file the same as phpMyAdmin upload, which Im using as my measure that my csv data file is formatted correctly.

Comment: connecting using mysqli is not an issue. I have also added screenshots to answer

Comment: See marks comment above. I think it is an issue with my csv file. I'm going to give this a try and let you know. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Don't use blank (white spaces) while uploading your csv